# SPARQL query poor performance

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, fuseki

```
select ?threadstarter  ?commenters (count(?postid) as ?postcount)
where
{
?subject1 bt:ThreadId ?threadid .
?subject1 bt:PostId ?postid .
?subject1 bt:UserUserId ?commenters .
  {
    select ?threadid ?threadstarter
    where
    {
      ?subject1 bt:PostId ?firstpost .
      ?subject1 bt:UserUserId ?threadstarter .
      ?subject1 bt:ThreadId ?threadid 
      {
      select ?threadid (min(?postid) as ?firstpost) 
      where
        {
          ?subject bt:ThreadId ?threadid .
          ?subject bt:PostId ?postid .
        }
      group by ?threadid
      }
    }
  }
}
group by ?threadstarter ?commenters
order by ?threadstarter
```

the above is Sparql query which I'm running against an fuseki endpoint of  dataset with 4.6 million  triples but it runs for hours and doesn't provide an output. but the same query runs fine against a dataset with 600k triples and throws output within 2-3 minutes.

what might be the problem?
is there any optimization to be done to the query?
or move to a some other triple store?
or any other alternate solution?

Comment: The middle SELECT does not appear to be necessary, just execute the pattern. Try moving the "select-min" subquery to the beginning of the block it is (put it just after "WHERE {").